# WCF Data Service and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf-data-services, odata, jqgrid

I'm testing WCF Data Service as shown in [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/30/using-jquery-and-odata-to-insert-a-database-record.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MGodfrey/archive/2010/08/26/878.aspx).

I show the ODATA result in a JQuery grid. Is there any grid that can support paging and sorting automatically?

In brief, I just want to define a ODATA url property for the grid, and if I click a column to be sorted, it automatically send the ODATA query to the WCF data service as well as pagination data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the KendoUI framework to [bind OData to the KendoUI DataSource](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/remote-operations.html) (and therafter to the Grid control).